# IF EXISTS and MERGE Statement

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-merge

I have data flowing into one table from multiple other tables lets say: Table_A
Then I have a Merge stored proc that takes data from table A merges it with Table B.

However, something doesn't seem to be right. If i truncate and load the data it works fine, but if i dont truncate and load, and just fetch the query by eachh hour I get the error message saying

Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Merge_Table_A, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

How can I overcome this?

I want to be able to incrementally load the data and not do truncate loads, but at the same time have a stored proc that updates or inserts or doesnt care if the row already exists.

Comment: Can you provide your sample code and data?

Comment: What's confusing you about the error message and therefore the solution?  You can't have multiple source records that match a target record, therefore you need to consolidate your source records so that there is only a single record per matching "key" before you perform the merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have **duplicate rows** in your target table which are loaded from your previous runs.

**Note**: Matching in a Merge does not consider the rows inserted (even duplicate) while running the Merge itself.

**Below is my repro example with a sample data:**

Table1: Initial data

[image]

Table2: Taget table

[image]

**Merge Statement**:

```
MERGE tb2 AS Target
USING tb1   AS Source
 ON Source.firstname = Target.firstname and 
    Source.lastname = Target.lastname 

-- For Inserts
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
INSERT (firstname, lastname, updated_date) 
VALUES (Source.firstname, Source.lastname, source.updated_date)

-- For Updates
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
   Target.updated_date      = Source.updated_date

-- For Deletes
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
DELETE;
```

When Merge is executed, it inserts all data without any errors.

[image]

New data in tb1:

[image]

When I run the Merge statement, it gives me the same error as yours.

[image]

**As a workaround** using one of the below options,

1. **Add additional conditions** if possible in the ON clause to uniquely identify the data.
2. **Remove the duplicates** from the source and merge the data into tb2 as below.

   ```
    --temp table
    drop table if exists #tb1;

    select *  into #tb1 from (
        select *, row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname order by firstname, lastname, updated_date desc) as rn from tb1) a
    where rn = 1 

    MERGE tb2 AS Target
    USING #tb1 AS Source
     ON Source.firstname = Target.firstname and 
        Source.lastname = Target.lastname 

    -- For Inserts
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (firstname, lastname, updated_date) 
      VALUES (Source.firstname, Source.lastname, source.updated_date)

    -- For Updates
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
       Target.updated_date     = Source.updated_date

    -- For Deletes
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
      DELETE;
   ```

Data merged into tb2 successfully.

[image]